# Quicklisp Cannot Install LIBSSL for Hunchentoot

Tags: common-lisp, clisp, quicklisp

I installed CLisp today on my Win7 PC. Please don't criticize my environment choices, but if this particular setup has flaws relating to Quicklisp and Hunchentoot feel free to point them out. I downloaded and installed Quicklisp and tried to use it to get Hunchentoot - however, it appears I have errors.

I type in (ql:quickload "hunchentoot") and all seems to be well, but for one thing - CL+SSL? For whatever reason that particular component won't install. Anyways, here's the output:

```
*** - Unable to load foreign library (LIBSSL).
FFI:OPEN-FOREIGN-LIBRARY: Cannot open library "libssl32.dll"
```

Does anyone know what this means, or how I can install this elusive library? I tried to install CL+SSL via Quicklisp, and I got the same error. "Cannot open library "libssl32.dll"

EDIT: I tried installing Hunchentoot with LispBox and got the exact same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quicklisp only installs ASDF systems. Then, if you look at the
[documentation](http://common-lisp.net/project/cl-plus-ssl/) of
`CL+SSL` you can read:

```
Note that you need the libssl-dev package on Debian to load this
package without manual configuration.

OpenSSL binaries for Windows may be found at
http://www.slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html (slproweb.com
is a 3rd party; if you have questions about the OpenSSL installer
they provide, please ask in the mailing list specified on the
linked page).
```

Conlusion: you've to install OpenSSL by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For future possible comers:
Installing / Loading Drakma (under Windows 8, but possibly not limited to win) using Quicklisp  with [lispbox](http://common-lisp.net/project/lispbox/) (again, not limited to) will output the same error.

A quick and dirty solution, is to use the "skip loading of package" option, which should leave you with a working Drakma without SSL :)